# rasa fill slots from custom action

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa

I'm trying to build a bot with rasa. At the very beginning of the conversation it should fill some slots with data from the database.

I have a custom action:

```
class ActionFillSlots(Action):

def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_fill_slots"

def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    example = "example"
    return [SlotSet("example", example)]
```

And in my domain.yml file i have set the slot like this:

```
slots:
  example:
  type: text
```

And a response like:

```
 utter_greet:
 - text: "Show { example }"
```

And in my stories.yml file, i have stories like:

```
- story: greet happy path
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: action_fill_slots
  - action: utter_greet
```

If I run the bot with `rasa shell --debug`
and then type something that matches the greeting intent, i get the following error:

> Failed to fill utterance template 'Show { example }' Tried to replace ' example ' but could not find a valu
> e for it. There is no slot with this name nor did you pass the value explicitly when calling the template. Return template without filling the template.

In my debug window I can see, that the slot has been set by the action:

> Current slot values:
> example: example

I'm using rasa 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? let me know

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher

class ActionFillSlots(Action):

def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_fill_slots"

def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    example = tracker.get_slot(example)
    dispatcher.utter_message(text = str(example))

    return []
```